# Having issue in installing Specflow plus Excel in Visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, specflow

Can someone please help me with this?

When I tried to install Specflow plus Excel in Visual Studio 2012 I am getting this error:

> Updating 'Specflow 2.0.0' to 'Specflow 1.9.0' failed. Unable to find a version of 'Specflow.Nunit' that is compatible with 'Specflow 1.9.0'.

Answer (score 0):

Take time to read this post, i had this problem before and i think there is still no solution on this issue.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/specflow/-mtegV9gCTQ

Answer (score 0):

We are working on updating SpecFlow+ Excel to work with the latest release of SpecFlow. We hope to be able to release a version within the coming month.

If you want to continue using SpecFlow+ Excel in the meantime, you will unfortunately have to stick with SpecFlow 1.9 for just a while longer.